# Failling to add library to android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, lib

I want to add Github library to my project in android studio , and I tried more than 7 time . Every time I have problem. I don't know what can I do  Please help me

[image]

This is [the](https://github.com/dEn13L/emojicon/tree/799e341c2e52c990a79c772dca9e9c0574e0abce) library.

Comment: Have you tried adding `tools:replace="android:icon"` to `<application>` in your manifest file?

Comment: I'd suggest reading the error message in full: `Suggestion: add tools:replace="android:icon" to <Application> element at AndroidManifext.xml:5`

Comment: thank you @SaurabhThorat

Answer (score 1):

The library you are using is using a value for `android:icon` in its manifest, and so are you. Since the compiler doesn't know which icon to use, this error is thrown. So in your manifest, add `tools:replace="android:icon"` to override the library's manifest like so:

```
<Application
    tools:replace="android:icon"
    ... >

    // Other elements here
</Application>
```